# SFML template shows >20 errors in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, sfml

I've recently downloaded and installed SFML into my copy of Xcode, and when I open a new template, 20 errors show up, saying that certain SFML objects have no member named whatever.

(I installed using the frameworks, but tried with the dylibs too)

Heres a screenshot of the errors:

[image]

How do I get rid of the errors?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you included or installed the wrong version of SFML. Member functions begining with a capital letter were used in `SFML 1.6`, that's not the case anymore in `SFML 2.0`.
Your code is obviously an `SFML 2.0` example so it doesn't match.

Comment: I've installed SFML-2.0 from the bottom of this page: http://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.0/ and used this tutorial to install it: http://www.mjbshaw.com/2013/02/building-sfml-2-with-c11-on-os-x.html

Comment: @mishajw126 Have you ever installed a previous version of SFML before ? `LoadFromFile`, `SetIcon` etc are all old-named methods. Same for `sf::Texture` `sf::Text` and `sf::Keyboard` not existing : they are changes from version 2.0.